# Error loading sitepage: cannot find the file specified. Exception 0x80070002

Tags: backup, import, filenotfoundexception

We have done a import from a .cmp and deployed several .wsp (webparts, usercontrols...) of our site in a new environment.

We can access to back-end (_layouts/settings.aspx), but we cannot access to front-end. An error is registered with an ID. Reading the logs, the error is as following:

> Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetMetadataForUrl(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32&
>   plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32&
>   plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)      at
>   UserControls.ControlTemplates.UserControls.MenuFex.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)      at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread. 
>   To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its
>   parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it. 
>   This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id:
>   {6D785596-4117-41E8-BED7-A3C3A9CF7F1F}  To determine where this object
>   was allocated, set
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks
>   = true. Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://***:2612/es-ES/fex/Paginas/default.aspx)). Tiempo de
>   ejecución=200,351441314469

We have look for that error, and we guess it is an generic error of file not found. Reading posts of people with the same error, I have seen that error usually log the name of the file that cannot find, but here It doesn't.

Please, do you know where I can found the name of the file that aren't being found?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It do mention an user control named menufex trying to find so list if that gives you a clue!

Comment: Yes, that's it. It was in the middle of the paragraph, I'm an idiot. Thankyou.